# How to write [Ss]tack ?[Oo]verflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

The logotype for *stack**overflow*** (and other Lo(W)J sites) is all lower case and uses boldface to separate the words, and that's easy enough to do if you can be bothered with the HTML tags.

But what if you're in a hurry, or talking about *stack**overflow*** on a site which doesn't support HTML editing in user-generated content? Is there a preferred way of typing the names of the sites?

I've noticed Jeff and Joel use "Stack Overflow" (normal English spacing/capitalisation) so this appears to be "official", but the Fog Creek site uses "StackOverflow", as do other users along with "Stack overflow", "stackOverflow" and just "SO" (only really works on SO itself or meta)

So, what's your preferred way of referring to the sites in the Lo(W)J when all you've got is caps, punctuation and spaces?

(For bonus points, watch Jeff "RegEx Boy" Atwood optimize my title!)

Comment: I have this magic convert to Wiki option I am just burning to try on this post :) But I am not that bored. **yet**

Comment: Turn the burn card, Diago, turn it now!

Comment: I'm far more interested in the answers than the rep, and it appears some people are missing the tongue-in-cheekiness, so I've voted to delete my own answers (I'll just upvote if anyone else matches what I said I used)

Can I Community Wiki my own question after I've asked it?

Comment: Can we have a *flag as boring* option?

Comment: @ramish Yes you can and if you vote to delete your own answers it immediately deletes. My response was also tongue in cheek thought.

Comment: Pretty harsh reactions for an acceptable question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fog Creek usage is incorrect.

in text:

Stack Overflow

in URL:

stackoverflow.com

Comment: Also, here's a rule of thumb if you, like OP, find yourself wondering how to write it: **Look at the page title** in the top of your browser window.

Comment: @Jonik - good suggestion, although I do work with at least one site (not Stack Overflow or a related site, I hasten to add) where the capitalisation of the page title seems to change with every page.